# Entity Framework - ON clause with two conditions

Tags: entity-framework

I have two tables:

Table `EMPLOYEE`:

| Id | Names | Seniority | Position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 001002 | 002001 |
| 2 | Peter Smith | 001001 | 002001 |
| 3 | Bill White | 001003 | 002002 |
| 4 | Mary Parker | 001002 | 002003 |

Table `PARAMS`:

| Cod | Nam |
| --- | --- |
| 001000 | Seniority |
| 001001 | Junior |
| 001002 | Semi Senior |
| 001003 | Senior |
| 002000 | Position |
| 002001 | Developer |
| 002002 | Manager |
| 002003 | Tester |

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    P.Id, P.Names, PA.Nam AS SeniorityName, PA2.Nam AS PositionName
FROM 
    Person P 
INNER JOIN 
    PARAMS PA ON P.CodSeniority = PA.Cod AND PA.Cod LIKE '001%'
INNER JOIN 
    PARAMS PA2 ON P.CodPosition = PA2.Cod AND PA2.Cod LIKE '002%'
ORDER BY 
    P.Names
```

How can I write this query in Entity Framework using LINQ?

Using `From`, `Join equals`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = (from p in _dbContext.Persons
    join pa in _dbContext.Params on p.CodSeniority equals pa.Cod
    join pa2 in _dbContext.Params on p.CodPosition equals pa2.Cod 
    where pa.Cod.StartsWith("001")
    where pa2.Cod.StartsWith("002")
    orderby p.Names
    select new {
       p.Id,
       p.Names,
       SeniorityName = pa.Nam,
       PositionName = pa2.Nam
    }).ToList();
```

Assuming your DbContext has defined the following:

- A DbSet called Persons that maps to the EMPLOYEE table and a
- A DbSet called Params that maps to the PARAMS table

Although the generated query will have the LIKE conditions of both joins in the WHERE clause; the behaviour should still be the same.